# How to use nginx as a reverse proxy with multiple ports

Tags: nginx

is it possible to use nginx as a reverse proxy like this?
I was looking at this post: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/self-hosted-ngrok-or-serveo-alternative
And wanted to get it to work with a dynamic port.

for example:

http://1234.mydomain.com --> http://localhost:1234

http://3333.mydomain.com --> http://localhost:3333

Is this possible with nginx?

I tried to create a wildcard domain and in nginx's sites-available I've put this:

```
server {
    #server_name tunnel.mydomain.com;
    server_name *.mydomain.com;                       #<----------
    server_name ~^(?<port>[\w-]+)\.mydomain\.com$;    #<----------

    access_log /var/log/nginx/tunnel/$host;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com.ml/privkey.pem;

    location / {
            #proxy_pass http://localhost:3333/;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:$port/;       #<----------
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }


    error_page 502 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

But it's not working, this does not distinguish different ports.

Comment: Use only the one single `server_name` directive (you can specify several server names). Use `\d` instead of `\w`. Try `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;` (do not use `localhost` domain name, do not use a trailing slash).

Comment: I've tried what you said but it's still not working, it only works if I use             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/;
by using this if I try to connect to xxxx.mydomain.com I get to the page I wanted (the strange thing is that I can connect to anything.mydomain.com and I will be redirected to the page I wanted)
if I replace 3333 with $port, it wont work and it returns error 500:
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port/;

Comment: Just checked in a sandbox. `server_name localhost ~^(?<port>\d+)\.localhost$;` and `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;` works for me as expected.